# Cherenkov Radiation Spectra

Tags: cherenkov-radiation

I've been looking into the Cherenkov effect recently and in particular I've been trying to plot an approximation of the spectra for photons emitted by it. However, I seem to run into a couple inconsistencies when I'm converting the Frank-Tamm equation into wavelengths rather than angular frequencies.

So, given the [Frank-Tamm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Tamm_formula) equation on the form:
\begin{equation}
     \frac{d^{2}E}{dxd\omega} =
      \frac{q^{2}}{4\pi}\mu(\omega)\omega
      \left(1 - \frac{c_{0}^{2}}{v^{2}n^{2}(\omega)}\right)
\end{equation}
I attempted to express it in terms of number of photons emitted per unit
wavelength and distance ($\tfrac{d^{2}N}{dxd\lambda}$) using the relations:
\begin{align*}
     dE     &= \tfrac{2\pi dN h}{\lambda} \\
     \omega &= \tfrac{2\pi c}{\lambda} \\
     d\omega &= -\tfrac{2\pi c}{\lambda^{2}} d\lambda
\end{align*}
and after some derivation, I received the expression:

\begin{equation}
     \frac{d^{2}N}{dxd\lambda} =
     -\frac{q^{2}c\pi\mu(\lambda)}{h\lambda^{2}}
     \left(1 - \frac{c^{2}}{v^{2}n^{2}(\lambda)}\right)
\end{equation}

However, when I compared this to a few other source, I found one [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5346099/) that
gives the same equation as:

\begin{equation}
     \frac{d^{2}N}{dxd\lambda} =
     \frac{2\pi\alpha}{\lambda^{2}}
     \left(1 - \frac{c^{2}}{v^{2}n^{2}(\lambda)}\right)
\end{equation}

While another [webpage](https://thespectrumofriemannium.wordpress.com/tag/tamm-frank-formula/) gave it as:

\begin{equation}
     \frac{d^{2}N}{dxd\lambda} =
     \frac{2\pi \alpha Z^{2}}{\lambda^{2}}
     \left(1 - \frac{c^{2}}{v^{2}n^{2}(\lambda)}\right)
\end{equation}

And a third [page](https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2016/03/10/cherenkov-radiation/) gave it as this, along with a full derivation:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{ d^{2}N }{dxd\lambda} =
    \frac{ 4 \pi^{2} e^{2} }{ h c \lambda^{2} }
    \left( 1 - \frac{ c^{2} }{ v^{2} n_{\lambda}^{2} } \right)
\end{equation}

As far as I can tell, some of the constants can be folded into the
fine-structure constant (α), but as far as I can tell not *all* of them.

Naturally, it is possible that some constants are simply omitted for the sake of
brevity in these sources, or that they are using a different unit system,
but in that case, what should the 'correct' equation be, in terms of number of photons
emitted per unit length and frequency in the SI unit system?